# How to use Xquery in Sql Server to search for character in column that stores XML data

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005, xquery

There is column named FileImage that contains XML data.

```
<root>
  <Image>    
    <File_image>02Jan12- Mfg--7.jpg</File_image>
    <Page_no>7</Page_no>
    <Logo>N</Logo>
  </Image>
</root>
```

I want to search whether text between tags  contains space character.
This is for checking invalid file name.

```
SELECT *
FROM mytable
where fileimage.exist('
   /Image:file_image//text()
    [contains(., " ")]') = 1
```

But error shown
*XQuery [mytable.FileImage.exist()]: The name "Image" does not denote a namespace.*
How to do this ? I am using SQL Server 2005.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM mytable
where fileimage.exist('
   /root/Image/File_image//text()
    [contains(., " ")]') = 1
```